# Create annotation for private static final array field to return copy

Tags: java, annotations

Can I create an annotation in java which when placed over "private static final" array field should treat it as public but when called should return its clone object. e.g

```
private static final  String[] test = {"Abc","CDE"}

public static final String[] getTest(){
 return Arrays.copyOf(test,test.lenght)
}
```

instead of doing all of the above code, It there a way by which i can do just this?

```
@notation
private static final  String[] test = {"Abc","CDE"}
```

Comment: Where did the getter disappear in the second example?

Comment: Actually thats what I'm trying to eliminate. Is this possible ?

Comment: You want to declare private a variable to share without getters??

Comment: Well it's definitely [possible](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html).

Comment: @JordiCastilla actually by default they are public but when we declare "static final" array as public sonar give following error. 

"static final arrays should be private" (This happens due to security reasons)

Comment: @Kayaman can you please explain how? Actually i'm struggling to find the right solution.

Comment: You should probably see how they did it with Lombok.